# Does B2C have a way of extracting form posted fields from an external identity provider?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have a B2C setup using custom policies that authenticates against Apple Id as an external identity provider. This all works, and we are able to get the email claim. However, the first name/last name fields from Apple are not made available in the JWT token and therefore are not in B2C as claims.

They are, however, presented to B2C as a posted form parm called 'user' during the first-time authentication. This is obviously a non-standard way of using the OpenId Connect protocol.

Does B2C have a way of extracting form posted fields (or is it on the roadmap)? I see it is possible to get query string parms via a claims provider when using the OAuth protocol, but I don't see the same for OpenId and posted form parms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The OpenID Connect technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile) maps claims from the ID token which means that additional authorization response parameters can't be referenced.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. As a follow on the question - does B2C allow for the creation of social identities via the graph API, assuming the user identifier is known? Eg. could we create a valid identity within B2C that could be used for social login?